# glclear() modifying image outside of glscissor() bounds in ios8 opengl

Tags: ios, opengl-es

The following code draws only a green box, when I am expecting both a green and red box.

If I don't have the second glClear() statement, the red box appears.

This leads me to conclude, since I have the scissor box outside the bounds of the red box, that the glClear() statement is not respecting the scissor box.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on?

```
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
int x, y, w, h;
x = 0;
y = 0;
w = 700;
h = 700;

glViewport(x,y,w,h);
glScissor(x,y,w,h);
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

x = 0;
y = 750;
w = 700;
h = 700;

glViewport(x,y,w,h);
glScissor(x,y,w,h);
glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: So it's still only a green box? Meaning, it does not paint the whole drawing area green? And if you don't have the second `glClear()`, it's also only a box, and not an entirely red drawing area?

Comment: Yes, it is just a green box, exactly at the rect specified by the second call to glViewport and glScissor. And yes, if I don't have the second glClear() it is a box at exaclty the rect specified by the first glViewport and glScissor calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to figure this out myself. I had to "reset" the scissor box at the end of the draw call. i.e.:

```
glScissor(0,0,viewPixelWidth, viewPixelHeight);
```

What was happening was that when the renderbuffer was being presented, the scissor box was being applied again, therefore everything outside the latest scissor box was not copied.

Comment: Or just disabling the scissor test once you no longer needed it.

Comment: Ah, yes. That seems like a better solution. Thanks!